# How to get a form to go to a certain page

Tags: html

I'm using checkboxes in a form to link to a specific page which has a different ending based on the checkbox checked.
At the moment it links me to http://localhost:13080/download?filesToDownload=p9mPFauS9VjjBXHFYCxWlg%3D%3D&submit=Download+File

but I want it to link me to http://localhost:13080/download/p9mPFauS9VjjBXHFYCxWlg%3D%3D

HTML:

```
<form action="/download" method="get">
        <table id="downloadFile" width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <table id="downloadFileDetails">
                        <tr id="dld">
                            <td id="dld" width="2%"></td>
                            <td id="dld" width="80%">File Name</td>
                            <td id="dld" width="10%">Upload Date</td>
                            <td id="dld" width="8%">Format</td>
                        </tr>
                        {% for file in file_query %}
                        <!--Jinja code that can be easily implemented into html code 
                        in this case it's a for loop-->
                        <tr>
                            <td id="dld" style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: center "><input type="checkbox" name="filesToDownload" value="{{file.key1}}">&nbsp </td>
                            <!-- checkbox which is to be used to check the files which user wants to download -->
                            <td id="dld"><a href ="/download/{{file.key1}}">{{file.file1}}</td>
                            <!-- Uses key that was captured in the UploadHandler class to be used as a link and filename is used as text on top of the link so user can know what they're downloading -->
                            <td id="dld">{{file.create1}}</td>
                            <!-- Displays date file was created -->
                            <td id="dld">{{file.type1}}</td>
                            <!-- Shows the file type of the uploaded file -->
                        </tr>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="submit" value="Download File" name="submit"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
```

Comment: It is a good question, can you use javascript to handle the url, or it is mandatory to use only HTML.

Comment: If it works I can, I'd would like to keep it as light as possible though

Comment: why did u use checkbox? for multiple download file?

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look.
Just added an `id=downloadFileForm` to the form and a small puere javascript code.

```
<form id="downloadFileForm" action="/download" method="get">
    <table id="downloadFile" width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table id="downloadFileDetails">
                    <tr id="dld">
                        <td id="dld" width="2%"></td>
                        <td id="dld" width="80%">File Name</td>
                        <td id="dld" width="10%">Upload Date</td>
                        <td id="dld" width="8%">Format</td>
                    </tr>
                    {% for file in file_query %}
                    <!--Jinja code that can be easily implemented into html code
                    in this case it's a for loop-->
                    <tr>
                        <td id="dld" style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: center"><input type="checkbox" name="filesToDownload" value="{{file.key1}}">&nbsp </td>
                        <!-- checkbox which is to be used to check the files which user wants to download -->
                        <td id="dld"><a href="/download/{{file.key1}}">{{file.file1}}</a></td>
                        <!-- Uses key that was captured in the UploadHandler class to be used as a link and filename is used as text on top of the link so user can know what they're downloading -->
                        <td id="dld">{{file.create1}}</td>
                        <!-- Displays date file was created -->
                        <td id="dld">{{file.type1}}</td>
                        <!-- Shows the file type of the uploaded file -->
                    </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Download File" name="submit"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    (function () {
        var form = document.getElementById("downloadFileForm");

        if (form.addEventListener) {
            form.addEventListener('submit', send, false);
        } else if (form.attachEvent) {
            form.attachEvent('onsubmit', send);
        }

        function send(event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            var options = document.getElementsByName("filesToDownload");
            var checkedFile = "";

            if (options) {
                for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
                    if (options[i].checked) {
                        checkedFile = options[i].value;
                    }
                }
            }

            location = "/download/" + checkedFile;
        }
    })();
</script>
```

What happens is that the submit event of the form is intercepted by the javascript and kind of redirected to the desired location.

If you use something like jQuery will be very helpfull and still light, just saying.

Hope it helps.

Comment: When I out that in I get an error in Google App Engine. So I dont think this will work

Comment: It works in my browser, any way, you never post nothing about Google App Engine so how could I knew. Try to check for other errors.

Answer (score 0):

Either you can use javascript to redirect you to your page using

```
window.location.assign("YOUR LINK")
```

Or you may use serverside script to get you redirection as you will be using some or the other language on server side. in php you can do it using

```
 header("LOCATION:YOUR LINK HERE");
```